# In Java, why 1L << 67 equals 8?

Tags: java

As asked in the title.

I know `1L << 3 = 8`, and long type is 64 bit. `67 - 64 = 3`. But still why `1L << 67` has the same effect with `1L << 3`? Why not something like "bit overflow" happens?

Is there any docs define this behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is long, then only the six lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. **It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x3f (0b111111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 63, inclusive.**

so, `67 & 0x3f = 3`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I'm looking for. Didn't even know Java did like that.

Answer (score 1):

The spec says that the right hand side argument in the expression 'a << b' only uses the lower X bits of b, X being the appropriate number depending on whether you're going with longs, or ints.

SOURCE: The Java Language Specification, section 15.19: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19